# how do I run file processor proxy from sample?

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm learning wso2 and working with this sample: http://wso2.com/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-example-file-processing/

I followed the instructions but when I start the server nothing happens. I don't see references to the FileProxy or sequences on the management console until I move the xml files to the deployment directory. When I do that I'll see the proxy and Sequences install but nothing else happens when I drop the txt file in the "in" directory.

I am not sure what I need to do to trigger the proxy. I'm not getting any error messages or anything. The server just kind of sits there.

What do I need to do to run the sample?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sample https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136056 in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1 to get a basic understanding of VFS Proxy.

Comment: Thanks Rajkumar, this put me on the right path. Turns out I had several configuration issues which was preventing the proxy from firing.